# Gesture is to physical motion as [blank] is to speech

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I am looking for an equivalent word for *gesture* in reference to speech.

'Overture' came up in offline discussion but it isn't quite right.

Comment: I'd say you have it backwards; *gesture* is a specific type of physical motion, and *speech* is a specific type of vocalization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Utterance*** would be an equivalent for gesture in reference to speech.

Utterances are vocal expressions and the smallest units of speech in spoken language analysis. They communicate a particular message and differ from phonemes.

Gestures are physical expressions. They communicate a particular message also and differ from physical non-verbal communication.

Utterances are used for vocal communication and gestures are used for non-vocal communication.

---

Additionally, [gesture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gesture)s are usually used in place of speech but they can be used along with speech as well. So, one gesture corresponds to one utterance:

> Other spontaneous gestures used during speech production known as iconic gestures are more full of content, and may echo, or elaborate, the meaning of the co-occurring speech. They depict aspects of spatial images, actions, people, or objects.
>
> **For example, a gesture that depicts the act of throwing may be synchronous with the utterance, "He threw the ball right into the window."** Such gestures that are used along with speech tend to be universal.

---

As a bonus, there is a book called "Gesture: Visible Action as Utterance" (by Adam Kendon) that compares gestures and utterances. (along with a detailed information about gestures.)